# How to insert characters at particular locations in text file

Tags: python, string, file-io

**Disclaimer:I have negligible knowledge of Python.**

In my college lab sessions, a lot of data is captured during experiments and I am required to insert that in a table and its plot in a Latex File, data is recorded in excel, I copy it from there and store it in a .txt file which looks like:

```
4.86    0.23
4.83    0.27
4.78    0.39
4.66    0.66
4.5 1.02
4.4 1.23
4.25    1.52
4.11    1.78
3.99    2
3.81    2.29
3.57    2.64
3.45    2.79
3.43    2.82
```

The corresponding part in Latex code is :

```
\begin{longtable}{|c | c |} 
\hline
$V_{out}$(in V) &   $I_{out}$(in mA) \\ \hline
4.86 &  0.23\\  \hline
4.83&   0.27\\ \hline
4.78&   0.39\\ \hline 
4.66&   0.66\\ \hline
4.5 &1.02\\ \hline
4.4 &1.23\\ \hline
4.25&   1.52\\ \hline
4.11&   1.78\\ \hline
3.99&   2\\ \hline
3.81&   2.29\\ \hline
3.57&   2.64\\ \hline
3.45&   2.79\\ \hline
3.43&   2.82\\ \hline
\caption{\\Output Characteristics for low input} 
\label{tab:output@low}
\end{longtable}
```

so in each line in my .txt file, I have to manually insert & and \\ \hline in each line, however since there are many such data files, huge time is consumed by this manual process, Can someone suggest a python code which would read the txt file , insert required symbols and return it back to me ?

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: ok, write script to read data from file line by line and append your sentence, finally add your lines into variable and save or rewrite into another file.

Comment: Disclaimer: I know very little python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import io

# watch the `r` in header, footer & adding to raw_data lines, `r` is raw, it's meant to take strings as is
header= r'''\begin{longtable}{|c | c |} 
\hline
$V_{out}$(in V) &   $I_{out}$(in mA) \\ \hline'''

footer = r'''\caption{\\Output Characteristics for low input} 
\label{tab:output@low}
\end{longtable}'''


with open('raw_data.txt', encoding='utf8') as raw_data, open('result.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as result:
    result.write(header)

    for line in raw_data.readlines():
        datapoint1, datapoint2 = line.split()
        result.write(datapoint1 + '& ' + datapoint2 + r'\\  \hline' + '\n')

    result.write(footer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have `data.txt` with all your experiments results:

```
4.86    0.23
4.83    0.27
4.78    0.39
4.66    0.66
4.5 1.02
4.4 1.23
4.25    1.52
4.11    1.78
3.99    2
3.81    2.29
3.57    2.64
3.45    2.79
3.43    2.82
```

You can read it and build your output file line by line:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

result = '''\begin{longtable}{|c | c |} 
\hline
$V_{out}$(in V) &   $I_{out}$(in mA) \\ \hline
'''

for line in lines:
    val1, val2, = line.split()
    result += f'{val1}&{val2}\\\\ \hline\n'

result += '''\caption{\\Output Characteristics for low input} 
\label{tab:output@low}
\end{longtable}'''

with open('result.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Output file contains:

```
egin{longtable}{|c | c |} 
\hline
$V_{out}$(in V) &   $I_{out}$(in mA) \ \hline
4.86&0.23\\ \hline
4.83&0.27\\ \hline
4.78&0.39\\ \hline
4.66&0.66\\ \hline
4.5&1.02\\ \hline
4.4&1.23\\ \hline
4.25&1.52\\ \hline
4.11&1.78\\ \hline
3.99&2\\ \hline
3.81&2.29\\ \hline
3.57&2.64\\ \hline
3.45&2.79\\ \hline
3.43&2.82\\ \hline
\caption{\Output Characteristics for low input} 
\label{tab:output@low}
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: dont we need to write string result to some file ?